# Can I easily get datetime with less resolution in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Obviously I can get the date and time from `datetime.datetime.now()`, but I don't actually care about the seconds or especially microseconds.

Is there somewhere I can easily get Date+Hour+Minute?

Comment: Just use the bits you need from the datetime type.  dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.day, dt.month, dt.year - or if it's just a presentation issue, use the appropriate format string.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can clear down the second and microsecond component of a datetime value like so:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
#Now get rid of seconds and microseconds component:
dt = dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```

This would allow you to compare datetimes to minute granularity.

If you just want to print the date without a second/microsecond component, then use the appropriate format string:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

>>> '2012/12/12 12:12'
```

Comment: This is perfect - I actually came across the `replace` function just after I posted this, and it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you might do a rounding operation on the quantity minutes+seconds+microsecsonds to the nearest minute and modify the that attribute according. For example 15:45:17 (m:s:μ) would become 16:00:00.

Comment: Example of function rounding to seconds: [How to change datetime resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72592640/320437)