# How to change datetime resolution

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a simple way to state that

```
a = '2020-01-01 19:30:33.996628' 
b = '2020-01-01 19:30:34'
```

`a` and `b` are equal. If the time resolution of `a` is changed to second, then `a` could be equal to `b`. How to implement it with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you treat both of them as `datetime` objects, you can use arithmetic operators on them. For example, you can subtract them and check if the result satisfy a condition (like less then one minute different) as you wise

Answer (score 3):

To make it clear, the following options are not the same as rounding, which could have an ambiguous outcome (e.g. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/7758804)).

### Set to next second

- Add the [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) difference between `1e6` and `a.microsecond`

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

a = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-01-01 19:30:33.996628')

a = a + timedelta(microseconds=(1e6 - a.microsecond))

print(a)

>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 19, 30, 34)

print(a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

>>> 2020-01-01 19:30:34
```

### Set to current second

- With [`.replace(microsecond=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace)

```py
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-01-01 19:30:33.996628')

print(a)

>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 19, 30, 33, 996628)

a = a.replace(microsecond=0)

print(a)

>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 19, 30, 33)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to use rounding for comparison:-

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser

a = '2020-01-01 19:30:33.996628' 
b = '2020-01-01 19:30:34' 

a = parser.parse(a)
b = parser.parse(b)

a == b
False

format_str = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

a_rounded = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.strftime(a, format_str), format_str)
b_rounded = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.strftime(b, format_str), format_str)

a_rounded == b_rounded
True
```

To this you can add flexibility according to your need like I have rounded up to comparison in `Minutes`.
So in your case the  format_str would be like this:-

```
format_str = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: `a_rounded == b_rounded `  is `False` with  `format_str = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: Note that it does not make much sense to convert `datetime` to a string just to perform a comparison.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers do not perform rounding to the nearest second which is normally the best solution for this kind of task. The function `datetime_round_s()` below performs this kind of rounding:

```python
import datetime

def datetime_round_s(date_time: datetime.datetime) -> datetime.datetime:
    return (date_time + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=5e5)).replace(microsecond=0)

a = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-01-01 19:30:33.996628')
b = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-01-01 19:30:34')

print(a)
print(datetime_round_s(a))
print(datetime_round_s(a) == b)
```

otuput:

```
2020-01-01 19:30:33.996628
2020-01-01 19:30:34
True
```

Note: If rounding bias could be a problem then the algorithm should be changed. See for example [Rounding half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_to_even).